# Correct quoting for cmd.exe for multiple arguments

Tags: cmd

I want to call

```sh
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" mysolution.sln /build "release|win32"
```

Unfortunately this does not work, because I get the error:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

As I understand, I need quoting for the spaces and quotes for the |, but I am only allowed to use the quotes once.

Any ideas how to quote this command line call correctly?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Note the `""` at the beginning and at the end!

Run a program and pass a Long Filename

```
cmd /c write.exe "c:\sample documents\sample.txt"
```

---

Spaces in Program Path

```
cmd /c ""c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Winword.exe""
```

---

Spaces in Program Path + parameters

```
cmd /c ""c:\Program Files\demo.cmd"" Parameter1 Param2
```

---

Spaces in Program Path + parameters with spaces

```
cmd /k ""c:\batch files\demo.cmd" "Parameter 1 with space" "Parameter2 with space""
```

---

Launch Demo1 and then Launch Demo2

```
cmd /c ""c:\Program Files\demo1.cmd" & "c:\Program Files\demo2.cmd""
```

[CMD.exe (Command Shell)](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work with RunAs: `RUNAS /savecred /user:DOMAIN\USER "CMD /K "CD C:\Temp""` ... can you help?

Comment: >RUNAS /savecred /user:computername\Administrator "CMD /K CD C:\Temp"

Comment: Docs say to use &&, not & to join commands.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @nmz787 : that is only `&&` if you have all commands enclosed in quotation marks (for example, `"command&&command&&command"` ).

Comment: @nmz787, moskito-x, a & b & c always executes a, b and c, but a && b && c makes it conditional. The command following && is only executed if the preceding one succeeded.

Comment: In case anyone else gets confused like me, this is different from how a .net console app reads the args param.

Comment: Note that this behaviour is special to *cmd.exe*. If the command starts and ends with quotes, everything inside will be preserved no matter the whitespace or other quotes. One of the "advantages" of the Windows command-line parsing system.

Comment: What happens when you have spaces in Program Path and you have parameters with spaces AND a double quote character?  It is a password parameter.

Comment: @JasonLWharton : `"...s AND a double quote character?"` an example would be nice.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k C:\ProgFile\php\php.exe -f C:\ProgFile\Passwords.php | ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" --new-tab %s'

Answer (score 2):

Spaces are used for separating Arguments. In your case **C:\Program** becomes argument. If your file path contains spaces then add Double quotation marks. Then cmd will recognize it as single argument.

Answer (score -5):

Spaces are horrible in filenames or directory names.

The correct syntax for this is to include every directory name that includes spaces, in double quotes

cmd /c C:\"Program Files"\"Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0"\Common7\IDE\devenv.com  mysolution.sln /build "release|win32"