# How do I tell fugitive my path to Git on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, vim, cmd

So I downloaded the fugitive plugin for Vim and try to get it running on my Windows 7 machine.

I don't have the path to `git.exe` in my `%PATH%` and I don't want to add it since issues could arise doing such.

My Git is installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\`. There's a config option for fugitive where I could tell my path to `git.exe` (`g:fugitive_git_executable`).

I've tried several flavours:

1. `'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd/git.exe'`
2. `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe'`
3. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe"`
4. `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe"`

But none is working. Seems like in 1, 2, 4, there's a problem with the brackets in the path. The resulting call of `:Git status` is

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c (C:\Program Files ^(x86^)\Git\cmd\git.exe status)
```

and the cmd window complains that `"\Git\cmd\git.exe" could not be processed` (translated from German).

How do I specify the path to `git.exe` so that I don't have to expand my `$PATH` variable?

Or more general: **when using the `system` command in Vim, how do I call programs that are located under `'C:\Program Files (x86)\`?**

Comment: Did you try to escape the brackets? It's worth a shot.

Comment: with `\(x86\)`, yes. Same problem.

Comment: Try escaping the spaces with the `^` character: `"C:\Program^ Files^ (x86)\Git\git.exe"`. `^` is Windows' escape character. If that doesn't work, try also escaping the parentheses with the same character.

Comment: Maybe reinstall git someplace more friendly, e.g. `c:\git`

Comment: @Peter: nope. This is not an option.

Comment: Another possibility: changed `Program Files (x86)` to `Progra~2`. That's its "short name" (which would have been its internal name back in the days of FAT filesystems).

Comment: I would suggest you open an issue on fugitive's [issue tracker](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues)

Comment: @echristopherson: yep. works. Make this an answer and gain rep.

Comment: @PeterRincker: IMO, this is no problem with the plugin. This was just the trigger. The real issue is described in the last sentence of the question (bold now).

Comment: I would open an issue as well. The plugin should escape spaces (it's sadly all too common for tools like this to assume no one would use spaces in a pathname).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your vimrc, add something like the following:

```
if has('win32')
    let $PATH .= ';' . 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin'
endif
```

This won't affect the value of %PATH% outside of Vim.

Alternatively, to get Fugitive to work as advertised, you'll have to patch it a bit.
In s:Git() replace

```
call s:ExecuteInTree('!'.git.' '.cmd)
```

with

```
if has('win32')
    call s:ExecuteInTree('!"'.git.' '.cmd.'"')
else
    call s:ExecuteInTree('!'.git.' '.cmd)
endif
```

and then put quotation marks around the path to the executable in your vimrc:

```
let g:fugitive_git_executable = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git"'
```

(See [correct quoting for cmd.exe for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891383/correct-quoting-for-cmd-exe-for-multiple-arguments).)

You might want to get in touch with the maintainer. I'd be surprised if this
issue hasn't cropped up before.

I just modify $PATH. Some programs *require* $PATH to be set correctly, anyhow.

(Plus: @echristopherson's solution is perfectly viable, but it's annoying to have to resort to that in the 21st Century.)

Comment: +1, good point. However, there MUST be a way how I could specify the path correctly. As well as the answer of echristopherson, this is a workaround.

Comment: Ended up using this way because it's pain-free. Accepting.

Answer (score 1):

The standard directory `C:\Program Files (x86)` can be abbreviated to `C:\Progra~2`<sup>*</sup>. This kind of shortened name is how long filenames or filenames with spaces in them were actually represented on FAT filesystems (which internally are restricted to filenames of eight base characters and three extension characters) from Windows 95 on, but it's still supported for compatibility in modern Windows systems using NTFS, at least in specific cases like the `Program Files (x86)` folder.

`C:\Program Files` is, similarly, `C:\Progra~1`.

<sup>*</sup> In Vimscript the backslashes should be changed to slashes unless they are either doubled up or enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Good point about slashes vs backslashes. Usually if you use slashes as a path separator in Vim, it will just do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

While the other two answers ([<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25891339/520162)<sup>,</sup>[<sup>2</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25910558/520162)) provide workarounds for the problem, playing around showed me that I need to specify the path this way:

```
let g:fugitive_git_executable = '"C:\\Program Files ^(x86^)\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe"'
```

Yes, it's really a single quote followed by a double quote AND (as if this wouldn't be odd enough) I need to escape the parentheses with `^(` and `^)`.

Although the issue is solved for me, I got no clue why I have to specify the path this way...

Comment: Worked for me. This is the real answer to this question.