# C# - print all files in a directory

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, printing

I'm looking for a way to print all files in a given directory.
Each file will be an Excel doc created by my program.

I have tried using PrintDocument but couldn't figure out how I actually specify to PrintDocument which file it should be printing...

```
private void PrintSheets(string filepath)
{
            //get directory
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
            //get all files in directory
            FileInfo[] Files = dirInfo.GetFiles();

            //loop through files
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                //create new print doc
                PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
                //select printer
                printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = cmbSelectPrinter.SelectedItem.ToString();
                //set filename document
                printDocument.DocumentName = file.Name;

                //print the doc
                printDocument.Print();               
            }
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the docs? The example there spells it out pretty plainly

Comment: you probably want to put some filtering like `*.xlsx` in your `dirInfo.GetFiles();`

Comment: Yeah probaby a good idea to. Thanks @T.S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print a file (document) you instruct the operating system to print it. Using [`Process.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8) with the print [`Verb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb?view=netframework-4.8), and the filename.

The OS (Windows) will find the correct application to open the document (Excel) and send it a command to print the file.

```
 var fileName = @"C:\Path To Your Excel file.xlsx";

 var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);
 startInfo.Verb = "print";

 Process.Start(startInfo);
```

PrintDocument is when you want to layout and and print a document yourself.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. Is there any way to define which printer to use or will it always just use the default?

Comment: You can use the printto verb. Read the documentation for the Verb property.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @PaulAlexander [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37527746/5174469) might also be of help. At least it was for me ;)