# How to send just one print process to print multiple files in c#

Tags: c#, printing

I have following code to print:

```
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (File file in fileList)
            {
                {
                    PrinterSettings currentPrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
                    printDialog.PrinterSettings = currentPrinterSettings;
                    currentPrinterSettings.Copies = (short)file.numberOfCopies;
                    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                    {
                        Verb = "print",
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        FileName = file.path,
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                    };
                    Process process = new Process();
                    process.StartInfo = processInfo;
                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForInputIdle();
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
        }
```

This code sends one print process per print job, but I want them to be integrated and sent to the printer as one process. I have found some solutions using external libraries like PDFSharp I have to pay, but I wonder if there is any solution not using such since I am not rich :D

Comment: Helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37527746/621520 ?