# Why can not environment created by Anaconda be used in Cmder?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, cmder

I used win10 64bit. The problem is that `conda` seems can not find env name, only env location.

```
*********************in system cmd*********************
#conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\czk\Anaconda3
py37                  *  C:\Users\czk\Anaconda3\envs\py37
testnumpy                C:\Users\czk\Anaconda3\envs\testnumpy

*********************in Cmder*********************
λ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
                         C:\Users\czk\Anaconda3\envs\py37
                         C:\Users\czk\Anaconda3\envs\testnumpy
λ conda activate py37
Could not find conda environment: py37
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

Above is the output in system cmd and Cmder. Also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54976890/2151275), and without progress.

Answer (score 2):

I also try and failed your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959918/anaconda-python-cmder-integration-on-windows-10/54976890#54976890) (also tried comments).

However, here is a workaround:

```
conda activate C:\Users\<YOUR_USER>\.conda\envs\<YOUR_ENV>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different installations of anaconda, one in each tool ('system cmd' and 'Cmdr'). You can know this by seeing the path for the `base` environment is different from each. System cmd points to anaconda in your user folder (`C:\Users\czk\Anaconda3`), and Cmdr is pointing to the ProgramData folder (`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`).

Here's how you can ensure that all the environments can be activated by name, regardless which installation or console you're using:

1. Create a `.condarc` file in your user home directory (if you haven't already).
2. Add `envs_dirs` to it, like below. This tells conda where to look up environments by name. See [docs on .condarc specification](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-env-directories).

```yaml
envs_dirs:
  - C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
  - C:\Users\czk\Anaconda3\envs
```